# Custom page created by a wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I am trying to figure out how to create a Wordpress plugin that adds a page to the Wordpress website on which it is installed.
I came up with the following which works and adds the page.

However, it's far from what I am trying to achieve:

1. How to change the entire page? Not just the content? Right now, it has all the header and footer and navbar.
2. How to have PHP code in the page, not just static content?
3. Is it possible to have everything under a url (https://some-url.com/my-plugin/) routed to this same page?

For example:

- https://some-url.com/my-plugin/          -> run my page
- https://some-url.com/my-plugin/foo/      -> run my page
- https://some-url.com/my-plugin/foo2/abc/ -> run my page
- etc.

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: MyPlugin
 * Plugin URI: myplugin.com
 * Description: MyPlugin
 * Version: 1.0
 * Author: Mike
 * Author URI: myplugin.com
 */

define( 'MYPLUGIN__PLUGIN_DIR', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) );

function create_page() {

    $post_data = array(
        'post_title' => 'Test of my plugin',
        # How to change the entire page? Not just the content?
        # Also, how to have PHP code in the page, not just static content?
        'post_content' => 'Place all your body content for the post in this line.',
        'post_status' => 'publish', // Automatically publish the post.
        'post_type' => 'page', // defaults to "post".
        'post_name' => 'my-plugin', // url slug (will 'slugify' post_title if empty) https://some-url.com/my-plugin-page?/
    );

    // Lets insert the page now.
    wp_insert_post( $post_data );
}


function plugin_activation() {
    create__page();
}

function plugin_deactivation() {

}


register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'plugin_activation' );
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'plugin_deactivation' );
```

Comment: I've added an answer of how to add a page from within a plugin that exists. Do you need direction on how to make a plugin?

Comment: That would be great too. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `wp_insert_post()`

Usage:

```php
$postarr = [
  'post_title' => 'My Page Title', // <title> tag
  'post_content' => '<p>page content</p>', // html for page content
  'post_type' => 'page', // blog post is default
  'post_name' => 'my-plugion-page', // url slug (will 'slugify' post_title if empty) https://some-url.com/my-plugion-page?/
];
$post_id = wp_insert_post($postarr);
```

For example, in your `$postarr` if you want it to be a page (not a blog post), use `'post_type' => 'page'`. For the page title `'post_title' => 'My New Page'` and so on.

See: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/

---

**Updated for additions to user question**

1. If you don't want it to follow the theme templates, then you'll need to hook into the 'page_template' filter and use a template file you create in your plugin. See: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3396/create-custom-page-templates-with-plugins
2. Depends on the situation, you can add code in your custom template, use [shortcodes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) or custom Gutenberg blocks. You can use [Advanced Custom Fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) on in the Admin UI and use `get_field()` in your code, etc. You have lots of options in WordPress. Once you have a custom template you can just add regular PHP in there.
3. Yes, but you'll need to use regex and create rewrite rules using `add_rewrite_rule()`. Here are links that help with creating rewrite rules in WordPress

   - [add_rewrite_rule](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule)
   - [add_rewrite_tag](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_tag)
   - [flush_rewrite_rules](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/flush_rewrite_rules/)
   - [WP_Rewrite API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite)

Comment: How do you define the url for that page?
Also, what if my plugin contains the page already created with all the structure, html and css? How can I add that page to http://ww.example.com/my-plugion-page?

Comment: K, I've added more info to my original answer.

Comment: Hi Phil, I updated my question. Thanks to your answer, I was able to create a plugin that adds a page but I am stuck on the next step to achieve what I am looking for. Any chance you can take a look at my questions? Thanks

Comment: @Michael K, I've add some notes and links in my answer.

Comment: Thank you. Ok for 1 and 2. I'll keep digging for 3. and maybe create a specific question about that if I don't get anywhere.